# How to specify Makefile output directory?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

i am currently working with the CLion IDE. In the CMakeLists.txt file, i have added:

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
#set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

and in the settings, i have set the path of the CMake Build files to the `build` folder.
However the `Makefile` is also in the `build` folder, but i want it to be generated in the source directory (for ease of use). I have googled this, but couldn't find an answer.

How can i make the Makefile generate in the source directory?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First, this is more of a CLion question.  Second, you can't.  In CMake you can either create the builds in the source directory or in a separate directory.  If you create the builds in a separate directory, then ALL the generated files go into the separate directory: makefiles, cmakefile output, and results of the build.  The source directory is treated as if it were read-only.  I don't use CLion but IIRC, CLion does not support CMake's "build in the source directory" capability at all.  So if you want to use CLion, you have to use separate directory builds.

Comment: I see. Thank you.